# Angular2 this.http undefined when run as prod.

Tags: angular

I have a simple service like the heroService here:

```
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

It works fine when running ng serve, however if I build with prod or run "ng serve --prod" this.http is undefined. I am importing httpModule on my app, so i dont know why it would not know what it is.

Does anyone know if i am missing something, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue with newer versions of angular.